# Discord bot showing remaining cooldown time before using the command again

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```js
let cooldown = -1


let cooldownString = `${guild.id}-${member.id}-${commands[0]}`
    if (cooldown > 0 && recentlyRan.includes(cooldownString))
      return message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed().setTitle(`SLOW DOWN`).setColor(`BLACK`).setDescription(new Date()-cooldown/1000))
    if (cooldown > 0) {
      recentlyRan.push(cooldownString)

      setTimeout(() => {
        recentlyRan = recentlyRan.filter((string) => {
          return string !== cooldownString
        })

      }, 1000 * cooldown)
    }
```

now this is in my commandBase folder so when i use  new command in a different file i would put a cooldown value as desired this code works it restricts the user from sending messages if the required cooldown isn't met but

**I am trying to display the the remaining time left to use this command for say the cooldown value is 10 seconds the user uses the command and tries to use it again and it say like you have 7 seconds before you use this command**

right now this gives me a value of -160.......